# View Model not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, view

Im currently practicing how to use WPF on C#, ive gotten the basics of it but im facing an issue, ive set up my code to open a new window when a button is clicked however the view does not update to how window 2 is supposed to look it just shiws the same view as window1 but the changing from window to window is working just the content is not changing.

Window one cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    

        private void OpenWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task1 f1 = new Task1();
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            f1.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Window 2 cs:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Task1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Task1 : Window
    {
        public Task1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Expenses objexp = new Expenses();
            //this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            //objexp.Show();

            MainWindow f1 = new MainWindow();
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            f1.Show();


        }

        private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Window 1 xaml and window 2 xaml are completely different but when i click the button it does show the windows 2 design.

window 1 xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480"
        mc:Ignorable="d" FontSize="18"
        Title="Finance Savings Calculator" Height="550" Width="900">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.529,0.484" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" OpacityMask="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <ColumnDefinition Width="46*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="179*"/>


        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="                                                    Welcome to the finance calculator" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="900" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,10,0,486" Foreground="Black" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontFamily="Imprint MT Shadow" TextDecorations="{x:Null}"/>

        <Button Content="HOME" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" Height="38" Click="Button_Click" Background="#FF20D6FF" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}" Margin="0,48,0,0"/>


        <Button Content="Task 1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" Height="38" Click="OpenWindow" Background="#FF20D6FF" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,118,0,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.DesktopBrushKey}}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="59" Margin="39,89,0,0" Text="This is a finance calculator. This app is designed to track your monthly expenses and income" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="677" FontFamily="Arial Black"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window 2 xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480.Task1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480"
             mc:Ignorable="d" FontSize="18"
        Title="Finance Savings Calculator" Height="550" Width="900">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.529,0.484" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" OpacityMask="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <ColumnDefinition Width="46*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="179*"/>


        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="                                                    Welcome to the finance calculator" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="900" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,10,0,486" Foreground="Black" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontFamily="Imprint MT Shadow" TextDecorations="{x:Null}"/>

        <Button Content="HOME" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" Height="38" Click="OpenWindow" Background="#FF20D6FF" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}" Margin="0,48,0,0"/>


        <Button Content="Task 1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" Height="38" Click="ButtonClick" Background="#FF20D6FF" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,118,0,0" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.DesktopBrushKey}}"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="427" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="696"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="305,195,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="305,291,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Gross Income:" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="178,187,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Tax:" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="261,287,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Next" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="261,408,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ScrollBarBrushKey}}" Click="OpenWindow"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I was told that INOTIFYPROPERTY change is the code missing but i am completely lost to how i would implement it in my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Send the Wall window as a parameter to the second window, where you set the `Visibility` property to `Visibile`, and if Task1 is created once, there is no need to create multiple instances.

The full code of the changes is given below.

change MainWindow to this :

```
namespace PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Task1 f1;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    

        private void OpenWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(f1 == null)
            {
               f1 = new Task1(this);
               f1.Show();
            }
            else
               f1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

change Task1 to this :

```
namespace PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Task1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Task1 : Window
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow;
        public Task1(MainWindow _mainWindow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainWindow = _mainWindow
        }

        private void OpenWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            mainWindow..Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the changes however I'm still getting that same error is it maybe my visual basic is faulty?

Comment: I changed the first code, did you apply those changes? And what error do you get?

Comment: Another point is that your code does not have a viewmodel and is a traditional code

Comment: I implemented the changes. the error im getting shows when i run the project when ever i click the button to show the Windows 2 window it does update to show it, it shows the mainwindow.

Comment: Maybe i confused myself do windows and views work in the same way when using WPF?

Comment: You used wpf like winform. No need to worry. Get acquainted (gain, obtain) with wpf controls and configuration, and then move on to MVVM, which is a common wpf architecture.